# Atualização do R no Mac

Tags: r

Como faço para atualizar o R e o RStudio, mas sem perder os pacotes que eu já possuo?

Uso Mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependendo do tipo de atualização a ser feita, não é necessário reinstalar nenhum pacote no R. Por exemplo, se a atualização for da versão 3.x.0 para 3.x.1 (ou seja, se o segundo número ficar constante), basta atualizar o R e o RStudio e, logo em seguida, rodar o comando `update.packages()`.

Por outro lado, toda atualização *minor* do R (por exemplo, indo da versão 3.5.y para a 3.6.1) exige que os pacotes sejam reinstalados, não importando o sistema operacional. Isto ocorre porque o R instala os pacotes em um diretório com nome referente à versão *minor* instalada. Por exemplo, para as versões 3.6.0 em diante, a pasta padrão é

```
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library
```

Perceba que a string `3.6` está no caminho do diretório acima. É possível descobrir onde os teus pacotes estão instalados rodando o comando `.libPaths()`.

Uma maneira não muito dolorosa de atualizar o R e reinstalar todos pacotes que já estão instalados é a seguinte:

1. Rode o comando `pacotes <- unname(installed.packages(lib.loc = .libPaths())[, "Package"])` para ver quais pacotes estão instalados na tua máquina
2. Salve o nome destes pacotes em um arquivo no disco com o comando `write.csv(pacotes, file = "~/Desktop/pacotes.csv")`
3. Após o R e o RStudio terem sido atualizados, rode as duas linhas abaixo para reinstalar os pacotes automaticamente

   `pacotes <- read.csv(file = "~/Desktop/pacotes.csv")`

   `install.packages(pacotes[, 2], dependencies = TRUE)`

A desvantagem deste método é que apenas pacotes disponíveis no CRAN serão instalados. Pacotes do Bioconductor, github, RForge ou similares ficarão de fora.

Comment: Obrigada, Marcus. Você me ajudou bastante. Abraço.

Comment: É muito bom saber que a minha resposta te ajudou de alguma forma. Por isso, considere [votar e aceitar a resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta), de modo que, no futuro, outras pessoas que passarem pelo mesmo problema tenham uma referência para solucioná-lo.